# How do I publish appsettings.json versions using .Net 7 and Visual Studio 2022

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-7.0, appsettings

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2022 and .Net 7.0.  I have created an MVC Web Application. I have two IIS Servers that I publish to using publish profiles within Visual Studio. One server is for staging / testing, and the other is production. The app runs fine on both servers.

However I find myself manually copying values into appsettings.json before each publish. For example, I have to change a connection string to point to a test db for staging, and a production db for production. Is there a way to automate this a bit like web.config transforms used to work?

My thanks in advance.